# Algorithm for array with `while` or `until` loop

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have:

```
array = [1, 4, -1, 3, 2]
```

I want a new array that follows the following logic:

- First element is located at index 0, so it is 1.
- Second element is located at index 1 (because value for index 0 was 1).
- Third element is located at index 4, so it is 2.
- And so on until the loop meets value -1, which is the last value, and it should brake.

The new array should be:

```
[1, 4, 2, -1]
```

I have:

```
def task(a)
  array = []

  a.each_with_index do |v, i|
    result = a[i]
    until a[i] == -1
      array << a[result]
    end
  end
  puts result
end
```

Comment: You are looping through the array. Instead, based on your question, you need to access individual element based on value retrieved from previous operation. Also `until` loop in running for infinity because `i` is not changing in the loop.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? You don't want to see others?

Comment: @CarySwoveland because it's the most understandable for me

Comment: Did I fault @Amadan's answer? It is in my opinion an excellent answer. If you were buying a car would you purchase the first one you saw that you liked, or would you want to see others before making your decision? In future consider waiting awhile before selecting an answer. There's no rush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others say, you need to change the index in your loop. Also, if you want `-1` in the result, you should exit at bottom. And `with_index` will give you indices in order, which is not what you want here. This will do what you want:

```
def task(a)
  i = 0
  array = []
  begin
    i = a[i]
    array << i
  end until i == -1
  array
end

p task([1, 4, -1, 3, 2])
# => [1, 4, 2, -1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
until a[i] == -1
  array << a[result]
end
```

This code is looping eternally - there is nothing to  change `i` .

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, you are looping through the array which is not what you require.

You could use a recursive method to handle jumping from one element to another based on previous value. Consider the following:

```
arr = [1, 4, -1, 3, 2]

def task(arr, n=0, result=[])
  if arr[n] == -1
    return result + [-1]
  end
  r = arr[n]
  task(arr, r, result + [r])
end

puts task(arr)
```

Comment: If the method is incorrectly called `task([1,4,-1,3,2], 3)` there will be trouble. It would be safer to write `def my_task(arr); task(arr, 0, []); end; def task(arr, n, result)...`.  This observation concerns recursive methods generally. You don't need `result` as an argument: `def my_task(arr); task(arr, 0); end; def task(arr, n); i = arr[n]; return [-1] if i == -1; [i, *task(arr, i)]; end`.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_array = [1, 4, -1, 3, 2]
last_valid_index = input_array.find_index { |entry| entry < 0 }
first_element = input_array.first 
last_element = input_array[last_valid_index]
middle_elements = (1..last_valid_index).map { |i| input_array[input_array[i-1]]}
output_array = [first_element] + middle_elements + [last_element]
p output_array
# => [1, 4, 2, -1]
```

you could to most of it on one line like so, but I think the more verbose version is more self documenting.

```
input_array = [1, 4, -1, 3, 2]
last_valid_index = input_array.find_index { |entry| entry < 0 }
output_array = [input_array.first] + (1..last_valid_index).map { |i| input_array[input_array[i-1]]} + [input_array[last_valid_index]]
p output_array
# => [1, 4, 2, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this option, just to avoid infinite loops or index out range:

```
i, ary = 0, [array[0]]
array.size.times do
  break if array[i] == -1 or array[i] > array.size - 1
  i = array[i]
  ary << array[i]
end

ary #=> [1, 4, 2, -1]
```

An infinite loop happens for example when `array = [1, 4, -1, 0, 3]`.
Index out of range can happen when `array = [1, 4, 6, 3, 2]`